# How do I launch marines in X4?

Tags: x4-foundations

I understand how to personally capture ships in X4 (and X3, if it's relevant) but I'd really like to be able to send the marine that I've been carrying around to go get the newly abandoned Falcon out there. I know how to task another ship to launch their marine and I see the neat little boarding pod zip out and snatch it up.

What do I need to do to launch a marine boarding pod from the ship that I am personally flying?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out this is easier than I thought:

1. First, make sure that you have marines on board. Recruits are fine if you're just claiming an empty ship. You can buy them in bulk at the wharves (which I think is funny... ;-).
2. Fly up fairly close to the empty ship. This is mostly to save time. I generally hang out at about 1000 meters.
3. Select the empty ship that will soon be yours by clicking on it.
4. Bring up the action menu by either right clicking or hitting 'f' (or whatever your action menu key is).
5. Select "Claim"
6. Watch a boarding pod launch from your ship and fly out to the empty one. Note that in version 1.50 is looks pretty goofy since the marine is basically riding the pod like a hoverboard (so don't look too close...).
7. Wait while the marine circles for a bit, docks and claims the ship.

At this point, you have a new ship in your fleet with a no-star captain on board. Time to send them off to repair any battle or sabotage damage and refit with new gear.